# Gorm Sharding - Error relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm, sharding

I tried to create a gorm sharded table using the code:

```
package dbo

import (
    ...

    "gorm.io/sharding"
)

func PerformSharding() {
    logging.LogInfoMessage("Performing sharding...")
    shardingMiddleware := sharding.Register(sharding.Config{
        ShardingKey:         "date",
        NumberOfShards:      1024,
        PrimaryKeyGenerator: sharding.PKPGSequence,
    }, models.DataEntry{})

    database.Db.Use(shardingMiddleware)
}
```

However, on saving to the model, I get the error log as shown:

```
ERROR: relation "data_entries_0473" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01)
[9.400ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "data_entries" ("...", "...", "date") VALUES ('...', '...', '20230617') RETURNING "id"
```

The data entry model is:

```
type DataEntry struct {
    
    gorm.Model
    ...
    ...
    Date      string `json:"date"`
}
```